# ASP NET MVC. How render a empty EditorTemplate inside a View.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, mvc-editor-templates

Inside a view, I would like to render a "EditorTemplate" partial but with empty fields as a "creating view".

```
@Html.Partial("EditorTemplate/TypeB")
```

The problem is:

If the main view already has a bounded model, the bounded model is sent to the partial view, and then a incompatible data type exception is raised. (in case the main view as a `@model TypeA` and the EditorTemplate has a `@model TypeB`

if i use the null as second parameter:

```
@Html.Partial("EditorTemplate/TypeB",null)
```

I got a "TypeB is required" Exception.

But if I add a empty dictionary in the requrest:

```
@Html.Partial("EditorTemplate/TypeB",null, new ViewDataDictionary() )
```

It works. It renders a empty Editor template with no model bounded.

Why the empty viewDataDictionary solves this problem? Is there any easier way to solve this problem?

Comment: By default, if you do not specify a model, the model in the main view is passed to the partial (it has to get a `ViewDataDictionary` from somewhere). Note you could also have used `@Html.Partial("EditorTemplate/TypeB", new TypeB())` to pass a default instance of the model.

Comment: Note also that you should not be using `Html.Partial()` to generate an `EditorTemplate` (the form controls will not have the correct `name` attributes and model binding will fail) and you should be using `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.yourPropertyName)`. And Editor Templates need to be in the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` (or `/Views/ControllerName/EditorTemplates`) folder and be named to match the name of the class (note that it does not matter if the property for `TypeB` is `null`)